# Airflow(v2.5.3) EKS. Tasks receiving SIGTERM with more than one scheduler

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, amazon-eks

we have our Airflow, which is using the next components:

```
KubernetesExecutor
postgres aurora 15.3
Airflow v2.5.3
EFS
EKS
```

We are running around 10 Dags.
Each dag has 10 parallel tasks.
Each of these tasks simply run a batch in another aws account, which contains a simple sleep 200 (Is our way to emulate some heavy process in another account.).

This said. what we observe is that we start all these dags, and at the start they complete successfully. However after some of them are completed, the rest start to fail.

We have debugged and we could see that for any reason, if we run them with only one scheduler, everything works, but when we add more then our tasks start to fail after a few minutes. Is then when our tasks receive SIGTERM, failing.

I confirm that our liveness-probe are correct (no errors on this).